# Mysql - unknown variable 'table_cache=64'

Tags: mysql, configuration

I use **Mamp Pro 3**. I upgraded Mamp's **MySql** to **5.6.24** using this script https://gist.github.com/tobi-pb/b9426db51f262d88515c.

After that I ran the Mamp Pro and MySql cannot be started. So I looked the mysql_error.log and found the following error:

```
2015-06-15 01:24:55 13139 [ERROR] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: unknown variable 'table_cache=64'
2015-06-15 01:24:55 13139 [ERROR] Aborting
```

After I google about this error, I get to know that I have to delete '**table_cache=64**' variable from `my.cnf` (MySql Configuration) file. So I deleted this variable from `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.cnf` file.

But the problem is that the same error still occurs when I start the MySql again. So I looked at the `my.cnf` file, '**table_cache=64**' re-appears automatically again. I deleted it again but it automatically appeared again when I start the MySql.

How should I solve this '**table_cache=64**' problem?

Comment: I remember an odd problem on some old version of OS X, when configuring postfix from the GUI resulted in some garbled routing rule.  Editing the file in an editor worked as expected.

Answer (score 10):

Version 5.1.3 "Renamed the table_cache system variable to table_open_cache. Any scripts that refer to table_cache should be updated to use the new name."  However, it did not become an error until years later, in 5.7.6.  Change to `table_open_cache`.

However, what does the line in `my.cnf` look like?  Sounds like there is something else wrong.  Change it to

```
table_open_cache = 200
```

(If you have a tiny machine, 64 might be better.  But in today's machines, a few hundred is a better value.)

Comment: Update...  2000 may be a reasonable value today.